# Storing Enhanced Ecommerce JS objects in html attributes

Tags: php, analytics, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

I am trying to set up Enhanced Ecommerce Product Clicks for our website and for it to work I need to send datalayer content to GTM/Analytics. To have all the info the datalayer needs I would have to send variables from one controller to another. **To avoid this I was hoping** to simply build an attribute that is a string json object that I can parse using an on click event that sends the data to GTM/Analytics.

```
<a href="" gaobject="{'name': 'Canon BP-820 Lithium-ion Camcorder 
Battery', 'id': '1227C142FH', 
'price': 1640.00, 'brand': 'Canon', 
'cat': 'accessories/camera-accessories/batteries', 
'position': 3, 'href': 
'http://test.site.co.za/accessories/camera-
accessories/batteries/canon-bp-820-lithium-ion-camcorder-
battery'}">...</a>
```

**My question is this:** Is doing it this way in any form dangerous to the security of our site or data collection? From what I understand if the data was to be manipulated through source code incorrect analytics could be captured, but that's about it?
And in this light, could there be a more efficient way of doing this?

Some notes:
The JS function does have an e.preventDefault() included. My intention is to have a single function in our main .js file that receives json objects, records and sends it to analytics as a datalayer, and then subsequently loads the page the href was set to initially.

Comment: This data will be visible with view source IMO. That's not very good in general. What about Ajax+SQL? You would pick this data up with php+sql, and then send Success message back to JS script. Either providing the GTM call server side, or sending values via Ajax back to JS as JSON instead of just the message.?

Comment: are you reading this geoobject attribute inside GTM?  Or are you using it elsewhere in your code to send to GTM?

Comment: @dockeryZ, It's only the string that I'm saving as a gaobject attribute in some elements. When the anchor tag is clicked a JS function is called which then looks for and parses the string as a json object, sends the data to GTM and then proceeds to the link.

Comment: @Volt, That's the thing I'm confused about though - if you add a datalayer for GTM you'd be able to see the code (well I mean, the values of the datalayer) regardless. With this I'm simply 'storing' it as an html element attribute in string format. I guess my question would be: Could this be manipulated for some known reason to either send fake data, or do something malicious to our site?

Comment: Well the datas that you posted look quite safe. But in the future you might have datas more sensitive or somebody else will put datas more sensitive. It's just like a time bomb. And what you want to do sounds so Ajax. It depends if you have database available of course.

Comment: @Volt So the reason I built the attribute like in the code I've shown above is because I would have had to capture the values for products etc. in a much more complex manner. Implementing it inside of an attribute enables me to simply slap a click and e.preventDefault() on it to capture what I want to, and then direct the user to the link. I don't think Ajax would be necessary for this? The data is simply caught by JS and sent to analytics through GTM's datalayer variables. This also does not involve our DB in any way.
Thank you for the help and comments. I believe I have my answer.